# How to check name of current user in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having trouble getting the display name of the current logged in user in firebase. I tried using `users.displayName`, but it doesn't display a user-friendly version. I just want the first and last name of the user. In my database, I do have firstName and lastName strings. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome, users first name" 
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get user info from Firebase, all users have a uid. The uid should be used as the key for each user node in /users.

```
uid_0
  gender: male
  name: jawad
uid_1
  gender: female?
  name: foxia
```

This is a common design pattern in Firebase.

With that, you can simply get any user by their uid

```
let usersRef = ref.child("users")
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath("the uid")

thisUserRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value... {
    let gender = snapshot.value["name"]
}
```

Or if you set display name .. you can get it like this

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    let providerID: String = user.providerID
    let uid: String = user.uid
    let displayName: String = user.displayName
    let photoURL: String = user.photoURL
    let email: String = user.email
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it... where did you get usersRef from?

Comment: I know it means user reference, but from where did you get it?

Comment: when i use displauName, it says that it is nil... could anybody help with this?

Comment: ca you share demo project ?